# Mask and issues

Tags: typo3, tx-mask

Regarding the mask, in backend mask have default configurations such as below:

```
general.json => typo3conf/mask.json
frontend.content => fileadmin/templates/content/
frontend.layouts => fileadmin/templates/content/Layouts/
frontend.partials =>  fileadmin/templates/content/Partials/
backend.backend =>  fileadmin/templates/backend/
backend.layouts_backend => fileadmin/templates/backend/Layouts/
backend.partials_backend => fileadmin/templates/backend/Partials/
backend.preview => fileadmin/templates/preview/
```

While installing our theme extension, we need to change the above mask configuration option values like below:

```
general.json => typo3conf/ext/<extension_key>/mask.json
frontend.content => fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/content/
frontend.layouts => fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/content/Layouts/
frontend.partials =>  fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/content/Partials/
backend.backend =>  fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/backend/
backend.layouts_backend => fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/backend/Layouts/
backend.partials_backend => fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/backend/Partials/
backend.preview => fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/preview/
```

We tried like below, but its not working:

```
plugin.tx_mask.general.json = EXT:user_ss4u/mask.json
module.tx_mask.general.json = EXT:user_ss4u/mask.json
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you try to override the settings via typoscript, which is -
 as far as i know - not possible.
The settings you want to change are saved in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` 
 in `['EXT']['extConf']['mask']` so there are two (okay, one with two ways) possibilities to change them:

**1.1 via Extension Manager**
Open the module "Extension" in the TYPO3 Backend and search for the mask Extension.
Click on the configure icon at the end of the row.
Now you should be able to change the settings.

Changes are stored in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`

**1.2 via Mask itself**
Open the module "Mask" in the TYPO3 Backend.
Click on the configure icon to change to the Configuration Tab.
Now you should be able to change the settings.

Changes are stored in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`

**2. via PHP**
You can add the following snippet to a file like the `ext_localconf.php` in `typo3conf/ext/<extension_key>` or in `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['mask'] = serialize([
    'json' => 'typo3conf/ext/<extension_key>/mask.json',
    'content' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/content/',
    'layouts' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/content/Layouts/',
    'partials' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/content/Partials/',
    'backend' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/backend/',
    'layouts_backend' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/backend/Layouts/',
    'partials_backend' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/backend/Partials/',
    'preview' => 'fileadmin/<extension_key>/templates/preview/',
]);
```

Comment: Hi Kevin  Thanks again for your help. We created the folder as mentioned. But after installation , the images are not showing and page contents are also not getting displayed.

Comment: Hi @Kevin Appelt   Thanks again for your help. We created the folder/extension  as mentioned. While installing  this extension we have to change Mask back end configuration. This is not working. Secondly - page tree contents are not properly imported i.e. all page contents are missing.  We have uploaded the extension here http://typo3sample06.softsolutions4u.com/user_ss4u.zip. Please help. Thanks so much.